# Hive command line parameter passing of date string does mathematical operation on dates

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to pass parameters to my Hive query as below:

```
hive --hivevar prev_year_sixmnth_date='2023-01-01' -e 'select ${hivevar:prev_year_sixmnth_date} as prev_year_sixmnth_date'
```

I get the result as below:

```
+-------------------------+
| prev_year_sixmnth_date  |
+-------------------------+
| 2021                    |
+-------------------------+
```

[image]

I think hive is performing some subtraction operation on the string 2023-01-01 and returning the result as 2021. How can I get the actual string passed as the parameter?

I have tried usinge cast as string, to_date operations on the parameter in the select query, nothing seems to work!

Comment: It seems your query lacks the apostrophes around the date. Did you try using double quotes for the query, and putting single quotes around the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive interprets the value '2023-01-01' as a date, not a string

To prevent the value as a string, you can add quotes around the parameter when passing it to Hive using the `--hivevar` option.

```
hive --hivevar prev_year_sixmnth_date="'2023-01-01'" -e 'select ${hivevar:prev_year_sixmnth_date} as prev_year_sixmnth_date'
```

It seems like this

```
+-------------------------+
| prev_year_sixmnth_date  |
+-------------------------+
| 2023-01-01               |
+-------------------------+
```